# How to read file excel with empty cells using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a file excel with 2 columns: `Name`, `price`.
I using EPPlus to read file excel :

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("" + dlg.FileName));
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row + 1; i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
{
    try
    {
         int j = 1;
         string name = workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();
         string price = workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Value == null ? string.Empty : workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();
```

I want to read file excel with empty cell from column price, I find many solutions and I saw a solution like that:`string price = workSheet.Cells[i,j++].Value == null ? string.Empty : workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();`

I debugged and I saw `price = true`.

And I used `OriPrice= decimal.Parse(price)` (OriPrice is a name of column in table in database) to add value from excel to database.
But I have an error.

I know error in line `string price = workSheet.Cells[i,j++].Value == null ? string.Empty : workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();` because `price = true`, I want to price = `string.Empty` or `workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Value.ToString();`

But I don't how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try just

```
string price =  workSheet.Cells[i, j++].Text.Trim()
```

No if else, should work.
I think.